# Registering an event/notification for location and speed in iPhone

Tags: iphone

iPhone doesn't allow background processes to run, but is possible to get a notification to your application when a user is in certain location or if a user reaches certain speed while moving?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to partner with a Mobile/Telephone operator - to consistently track (with user's consent offcourse) any Mobile.

So for a hypothetical scenario would be:-

1. Scope of your App: Tell the User when he has to get down on a journey.
2. The user uses the iphone app to give consent to track that journey
3. S/he selects the destination where he wants the alert interactively
4. The iphone app sends these information to a server-side program
5. The user may quit the iphone app
6. The server-side program can poll the Mobile Operators Location Servers to know the current location of the User's specific mobile - periodically
7. On locating it near the destination, the server-side app sends a push notification to the iPhone
8. The iPhone receives a Push Alert

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just set up a Core Location delegate to receive updates, and check the speed property of incoming CLLocation objects. When you get the desired speed, post an NSNotification.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible. You have to have the application open in order to capture the speed or or location. You cannot register an application to launch based on the speed or location.